# Firebase Cloud Messaging onMessageSent not called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm switching from GCM to FCM. I only use it to send messages to my server trough FCM. I extended `FirebaseMessagingService` to implement the callbacks. For example, `onSendError()` works just fine, but `onMessageSent()` is never executed... I don't know if it is relevant, but I send the 'ack' stanza from my server when the message is received.

**My FirebaseMessegingService class:**

```
public class FCMListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public FCMListenerService() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeletedMessages() {
        Log.d("wouter", "onDeletedMessages: ");
        super.onDeletedMessages();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageSent(String msgID) {
        Log.e("wouter", "##########onMessageSent: " + msgID );
        super.onMessageSent(msgID);
        Database database = new Database(this);
        database.confirmFCMMessageSend(msgID);
        database.closeDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSendError(String msgID, Exception exception) {
        Log.e("wouter", "onSendError ", exception );
        super.onSendError(msgID, exception);
        Database database = new Database(this);
        database.eraseFCMMsgIDFromFGMMessageLog(msgID);
        database.closeDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    }
}
```

**And the relevant part of my Manifest:**

```
<service android:name=".FCM.FCMListenerService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: How many messages did you try to send? The acks to onMessageSent are batched so when you send a message successfully you may not receive a callback for some time. This is to help with battery life. Try sending 10 or more upstream messages, you should receive an onMessageSent callback after about 10 messages.

Comment: I tested a lot and did send a bunch of messages, so that's not it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had the same problem and the second part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39764289/5888688) fixed it for me.
Basically, you have to set the TTL at the message you send.
Something like:

```
RemoteMessage myMessage = new RemoteMessage.Builder(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com").setMessageId(id).setData(data).setTtl(86400).build();
```

Comment: I reported this issue to the Firebase support. They acknowledged it as a bug, but couldn't provide a timeline for a fix. So maybe at some point in the future, this will be fixed. Checking out the release notes of new versions once in a while wouldn't hurt, I guess.

Comment: This issue is still there in Firebase api.