# onMessageSent of FirebaseMessagingService is not called accordingly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use `FCM` to send `UpStream Message`, so I followed the tutorial on google and it works.

As shown in the code below in `MainActivity`, I send `Upstream message` when the button is clicked, then in `MyAndroidFirebaseMsgService` I should see a `Log` message as shown 
below in `MyAndroidFirebaseMsgService`.

But what happen is, the `Log` messages in `MyAndroidFirebaseMsgService` in `onMessageSent` in do not get displayed even I kept pressing the button several times.
the `Log` message in `MyAndroidFirebaseMsgService` in `onMessageSent` can be displayed only if sent a `downstream message`from `FCM` to the App, in this case, both the `Logs` in 
in `MyAndroidFirebaseMsgService` will be displayed.

Please let me know why the Log message in `onMessageSent` is not getting displayed once there is an `UpStream message` sent?and how to fix it.

**Mainactivity**:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mBtnSendUpstreamMsg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send_upstream_message);
    mBtnSendUpstreamMsg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FirebaseMessaging fm = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
            fm.send(new RemoteMessage.Builder("673xxxxx" + "@gcm.googleapis.com")
                    .setMessageId("2")
                    .addData("my_message", "Hello World")
                    .addData("my_action","SAY_HELLO")
                    .build());
        }
    });
}
```

**MyAndroidFirebaseMsgService**:

```
public class MyAndroidFirebaseMsgService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private final static String TAG = MyAndroidFirebaseMsgService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onMessageSent(String s) {
    super.onMessageSent(s);
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageSent: upstream message");
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: downstream message");
    //Log data to Log Cat
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived->From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived->Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    //create notification
    createNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

private void createNotification( String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent( this , ResultActivity.class );
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this , 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri notificationSoundURI = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Android Tutorial Point FCM Tutorial")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel( true )
            .setSound(notificationSoundURI)
            .setContentIntent(resultIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, mNotificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Cloud Messaging onMessageSent not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471510/firebase-cloud-messaging-onmessagesent-not-called)

Comment: The answer and comments for the question I referenced indicate that because of a bug in Firebase, `onMessageSent()` is not invoked unless the `RemoteMessage` is built with `setTtl()`.  I didn't observe this with 11.0.2.  Note that  there is a delay of ~20 minutes before `onMessageSent()` is called.  This is [explained in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream#handle_upstream_message_callbacks): _To optimize network usage, FCM batches responses to onMessageSent and onSendError, so the ack may not be immediate for each message_

Comment: but the link you provided does not answer my question, because in the link you provided i should use `RemoteMessage` and it is not defined in my code..any idea how to import/use `RemoteMessage`class

Comment: I updated my comment.  You should not need to `setTtl()` if you are using version 11.0.2.  Are you waiting 20 minutes for `onMessageSent()` to be called?

Comment: i am using   10.0.1....compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'

Comment: You may need to use `setTtl()`.  It is a method of `RemoteMessage.Builder`.  You can add it to your builder, for example after `setMessageId("2")`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **is possible** to send a Firebase messaging push notification and receive it in all app life cycles using `onMessageReceived`.

But is necessary to change the default Firebase behaviour, intercepting the intent request before everything else.

** **IMPORTANT NOTE** **

This was a **pretty stupid** idea from Firebase by remove the developers processment capability when the FCM message arives with the `notification message` format, but not for `data message`.

This created a bunch of "**workarounds**" in many solutions, which made the analythics and everything else being messed up.

If I had designed this solution, I would always call the `onMessageReceived` method with a `completion handle`. Let the developer decide what to do (free tip for you, Firebase).

Use `onMessageReceived` is the correct way to do. This method is the only one who brings `RemoteMessage` object, that have every information what you need. It was designed for it. You are on correct path.

** **HOW TO DO** **

In your Firebase Class `MyAndroidFirebaseMsgService`, which extends `FirebaseMessagingService`, override the public method `handleIntent` to intercep the intent request before Firebase catch it.

```
    @Override
    public void handleIntent(Intent intent){

        if(intent.hasExtra("google.message_id")){
            intent = handleFirebaseIntent(intent);
        }

        super.handleIntent(intent);
    }
```

After, transform the `notification message` package into an `data message`, removing all `"gcm.notification.%"` and `"gcm.n.%"` extras from intent, and translating `"gcm.notification.title"`, `"gcm.notification.body"` and `"gcm.notification.image"` elements into what you need:

```
    // Thank you Google, for that brilliant idea to treat notification message and notification data
    // differently on Android, depending of what app life cycle is. Because of that, all the developers
    // are doing "workarounds", using data to send push notifications, and that's not what you planned for.
    // Let the developers decide what to do on their apps and ALWAYS deliver the notification
    // to "onMessageReceived" method. Its simple, is freedom and its what the creative ones need.
    private Intent handleFirebaseIntent(Intent intent){

        //printIntentExtras(intent);

        String FCM_TITLE_KEY = "gcm.notification.title";
        String FCM_BODY_KEY = "gcm.notification.body";
        String FCM_IMAGE_KEY = "gcm.notification.image";

        String title = intent.getStringExtra(FCM_TITLE_KEY);
        String body = intent.getStringExtra(FCM_BODY_KEY);
        String image = intent.getStringExtra(FCM_IMAGE_KEY);

        // Remove the key extras that identifies an Notification type message
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
                if (key.startsWith("gcm.notification.") || key.startsWith("gcm.n."))
                {
                    intent.removeExtra(key);
                }
            }
        }

        Boolean isTitleEmpty = StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(title);
        Boolean isBodyEmpty = StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(body);
        Boolean isImageEmpty = StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(image);

        // Notification title and body has prevalence over Data title and body
        if(
            !isTitleEmpty || !isBodyEmpty || !isImageEmpty
        ){

            // This is my personalized translation method, designed for my solution.
            // Probably you gonna need to do it by your own

            String contentData = intent.getStringExtra(Definitions.PUSH_NOTIFICATION_CONTENT);

            Map<String, Object> content;
            if(StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(contentData)){

                content = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                content.put(Definitions.NOTIFICATION_ID, new Random().nextInt(65536) - 32768);
                content.put(Definitions.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_KEY, "basic_channel" );

            } else {
                content = JsonUtils.fromJson(new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType(),contentData);
            }

            if(!isTitleEmpty) content.put(Definitions.NOTIFICATION_TITLE, title);
            if(!isBodyEmpty) content.put(Definitions.NOTIFICATION_BODY, body);
            if(!isImageEmpty){
                content.put(Definitions.NOTIFICATION_BIG_PICTURE, image);
                content.put(Definitions.NOTIFICATION_LAYOUT, NotificationLayout.BigPicture.toString());
            }

            contentData = JsonUtils.toJson(content);
            intent.putExtra(Definitions.PUSH_NOTIFICATION_CONTENT, contentData);
        }

        //printIntentExtras(intent);

        return intent;
    }

    private void printIntentExtras(Intent intent){
        Bundle bundle;
        if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
            for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(key + " : " + (bundle.get(key) != null ? bundle.get(key) : "NULL"));
            }
        }
    }
```

You can check [my entire solution here](https://github.com/rafaelsetragni/awesome_notifications).